# SVG rendering issue on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg, safari

I was trying to render SVG on browsers and shockingly I found that it is rendering differently on different browsers.

The SVG was suppose to be **round** in shape and firefox got it right, But Chrome(Version 32.0.1700.102) and Safari(6.1.4) are rendering it as **rectangle**.

[image: screenshot from Chrome]
[image: screenshot from firefox]
Here is the SVG that I used : https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bidpress-image-processing-module/1404199746.svg

Are there any possible fix or workaround for this issue?

Comment: It seems to me that the link in the question goes to a .png. We would need the SVg source code (preferably in the question itself) in order to suggest workarounds.

Comment: @RobertLongson , Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated with direct link to SVG.

Comment: The shape is a path. I suggest using an SVG `<ellipse>` element instead as a workaround.

Comment: I've filed http://crbug.com/403344 for this, looks like the wrong gradient stop is used for the padding.